# Angular 9.1.5 upgrade issue

Tags: angular-cli

I've upgraded my project from Angular 9.0.5 to 9.1.5 and now I have an issue when compiling:

```
ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined
    at resolveAlias (F:\tmp\myt-master\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:35155:37)
    at checkAliasSymbol (F:\tmp\myt-master\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:62613:26)
    at checkImportBinding (F:\tmp\myt-master\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:62644:13)
```

**New version installed**

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.4
Node: 13.7.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.5
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.4
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.4
@angular/cdk                      9.1.1
@angular/cli                      9.1.4
@angular/material                 9.1.1
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.4
@schematics/angular               9.1.4
@schematics/update                0.901.4
rxjs                              6.5.4
typescript                        3.7.5
webpack                           4.42.0
```

I've tried downgrading to typescript 3.7.2 with no success
Would very much appreciate any help

Comment: Please show us the code which throws that error.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36993

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved by downgrade which is probably not a fix at all but it works !

#### Step 1 :

Permanently delete your node modules.

#### Step 2 :

**RUN THIS COMMAND ON YOUR CONSOLE**

```
npm install @angular/core@9.1.4 @angular/animations@9.1.4 @angular/common@9.1.4 @angular/forms@9.1.4 @angular/platform-browser@9.1.4 @angular/router@9.1.4 @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@9.1.4 @angular/compiler@9.1.4 @angular/compiler-cli@9.1.4 @angular/language-service@9.1.4
```

#### Step 3 :

**CONGRATULATIONS YOU SUCCESSFULLY DOWNGRADED THE DEPENDENCIES AND THE TYPEERROR IS RESOLVED SUCCESSFULLY**
Now you may try these !

```
ng serve --open
ng build
.............etc
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working.So it seems the issue is in the 9.1.5

Comment: do I have to install all the packages you mentioned or     ng update @angular/cli@9.1.4 @angular/core@9.1.4   will do the job

Comment: @dahas you need to downgrade all the packages because of the dependencies linked to each others !